# What files are required for ASP.NET MVC 3's unobtrusive client-side validation to work?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

What files are required for ASP.NET MVC 3's unobtrusive client-side validation to work?

And is it compatible with jQuery 1.6.3?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is compatible with jQuery 1.6.3

You need : jQuery, jQuery Validate (jquery.validate.js) and the MVC plugin for unobtrusive client validation with jQuery Validate (jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js)

Note that you need to have client validation enabled in Web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```